# Deleting orphaned files from iphone

Tags: iphone

Is there an easy way to remove all files NOT referenced by "iTunes Library.itlp" on my iphone? I need to free up some space and I know I have audio files saved on the iphone that are just orphaned..

Comment: How do you know that you have these orphaned files?

Answer (score 1):

Backup the phone using itunes and then restore to defaults and reload the backup. That should delete any files not in the itunes database. If the files are used by other apps they might still hang around and you might need to tell itunes not to load that app any more.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the free [iPhone Explorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iphoneexplorer/), or [iPhone Disk](http://www.macroplant.com/phonedisk/?ipeMac) (US$19.95) for Mac or Windows? They enable you to view your iPod or iPhone in the Finder, browse the file directory on the device, and copy or delete files on the device directly, without using iTunes.

Answer (score -1):

yes, but the only way i know of requires mobil terminal, which requires jailbreaking and is unfortunately only available on software no later than iOS 2.0

Comment: This is not true. An alternative would be to jailbreak and SSH into your phone, allowing you to delete the files. Additionally, MobileTerminal works with iOS 3 and up: http://code.google.com/p/mobileterminal/